# How to determine if ANY element in an list is found in a .txt file?

Tags: python, arrays, tweepy

I have imported by Tweety a timeline of my business opponent. 
I want to do a search of some keywords imported from file.

```
f = open('base.txt','r')
with open('base.txt') as f:
    content = [f.read()]
```

I want to find if he used any words from my keywords list.
Can you help me?

Comment: if content in variable:
 print("is ok")
else:
 print("nothing")

Comment: I think @tglaria is looking for the code that you've already tried.  Also some sample data would be helpful.

Comment: The keyword you search for is intersection.

Comment: mcf = api.user_timeline(id="georgehwbush")
 mcf = str(mcf)
 print(mcf)

[Status(contributors=None, truncated=True, text=u'In my case, one of the few good things about becoming the oldest president -- or anything -- is

Comment: intersection: `set(mine) & set(his)`

Comment: @Kamil is updated answer closer to what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know and with little information from your question,
mmap library serve your problem

```
import mmap

with open('test.txt', 'rb', 0) as file, mmap.mmap(file.fileno(), 0, 
access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) as s:
# test.txt has a sentence "where am i? I am here!"
    keywords = ["ie","ame!","here"]
    for idx,keyword in enumerate(keywords):
        if s.find(bytes(keyword,encoding ="utf8")) != -1:
            print('True')
            print("Keyword is" ,keyword)
        else:
            print('Nothing')
# Nothing
# Nothing
# True
# Keyword is here
```

Comment: thank you! i cant give you upvote (im to young here) but you can feel that upvote in hearth ;)

Comment: Great and be aware that some words like "here" and "where", "somewhere" and "where" may return positives. So the code has to be adjusted  to return the actual word from the txt file for all positives to avoid false positives.

Comment: Um, why use memmap here? What's the advantage?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Good question :) [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483163/advantages-of-mmap-vs-fileinput)  is what i referred before using it.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. What do you suppose is the advantage here? why not iterate the file line-by-line? You don't really need random-access to the file...

Comment: We dont really need to iterate line-by-line, since we looking for target keywords and not sentences. Yes we do iterate line-by-line and look for keywords but that add up few more lines in above code but i would like to keep the code intact. Yes, we don't need the optional parameter `access =mmap.ACCESS_READ`  but wouldn't that be better than the default value for `access` `mmap.ACCESS_WRITE`  which is not relevant to the problem we have here?

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your list of words, checking if each word appears in the other list.

```
for word in list:
    if word in other_list:
        print(word)
```

Comment: I think the question is to look for the word in .txt file not in another list. Question is edited wrong. When you look at the sample code from @Kamil, it is clear that, he is trying to look for the words from .txt file not from another list.